# comparing phone number from my contact list and an array of numbers

Tags: android, string, listview, getview

hi need help please while trying to compare two strings but my "if" never return true i want to set image visible or invisible just if my number exist in my array here is my code :

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alluser_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
        holder.tvname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        holder.tvPhoneNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);
        holder.img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null)||((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);


    if (holder.tvname != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvname.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
    }
    if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
            && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i <Emc2Contacts.length; i++) {

             if (objBean.getPhoneNo().toString().equals(Emc2Contacts[i].toString())){

                 holder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             } else {                 
                 holder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
             }
    }
```

when i compare my contact number to a simple string like this

```
if(objBean.getPhoneNo().toString().equals("+2213334534")){
   holder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

i have what i expect. any help will be a pleasure

Comment: This seems like it would be a great example to get acquainted with the debugger. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `if (objBean.getPhoneNo().toString().equals(Emc2Contacts[i].toString()))` to check the values?

Comment: not yet @RyPope let me try and let you now !

Comment: i add a Log just after my 'if' but i never see have result when i put i in the 'else' statement i see the value of objBean.getPhoneNo() also for the array

Comment: And are they equal? No additional dashes or spaces in either?

Comment: i see lot of numbers here but my Log.i("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEe", objBean.getPhoneNo().toString());    Log.i("RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRr",SQLiteCrudEmc2.Emc2Contacts[i].toString()) my two logs are here and result are not the same

Comment: help plzz ! am blocked